Remove "performance chart" slider widget from run tool window?
The collapsed (non-functional) performance chart window is just sitting there wasting an entire vertical column of space whenever I'm not doing profiling (which is most of the time).
I would like to reclaim that wasted space somehow - any suggestions?
There doesn't seem to be any options on right-click (like where you can "hide" a tool window).  When I "drag" the widget, the whole column gets highlighted, but I don't seem to be able to actually drag it anywhere.
It's fine if the way to disable the performance widget is to disable all JVM profiling functionality.


Request to disable the performance widget is requested as a usability issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-361727/Allow-removal-of-performance-chart-from-run-tool-window
Note the comment on that issue from Serge:
It seems the performance widget is doing more than just take up space in the UI.  It sounds like it's constantly issuing a bunch of JMX requests (many times per second) against the running application.

Invoke Find Action from the Help menu (Command/Ctrl+Shift+A) and search for Registry in the popup that appears to open the Registry dialog. Disable the profiler.widget.in.run.console option there (you can type in the dialog to search for this key). Be careful with the other configuration options, because it is possible to break your IntelliJ IDEA installation with an incorrect setting.
